# Active Collab API issue with attach file or image

Tags: php, api, activecollab

I am creating API for creates task in Active Collab and I have been successful for `get` and `set` name of new task, message and due date.

However,  when I insert image or file it's not creating task.

Below is my code so please help me to solve it.

```
try {
    API::call('projects/60/tasks/add', null, array(
        'task[name]' => $_POST['name'],
        'task[body]' => $_POST['message'],
        'task[priority]' => $priority,  
        'task[due_on]' => $date,
        'task[assignee_id]' => 21,
    ), array(
       'a.png' /* This array is for attach image to this task but not working in my case and I found this from https://help-classic.activecollab.com/books/api/sdk.html */
    ));
    echo 'Ticket Created Successfully.';

} catch(AppException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage() . '<br><br>';
    var_dump($e->getServerResponse());
}
```

Comment: are there any return message or not??
$e->getMessage()

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `a.png` with an absolute path to an existing file on file system, for example `/path/to/my/image.png`.

Comment: @llija I have applied full path before asking question here however it didn't work. so please if you have any other solution then you can help me.

Comment: That's how request with files is prepared. I'm unsure why it does not work in your env.

Comment: @llija can you help me to attach image using Active collab API.I tried below code but it's not working.
try{
API::call('projects/60/tasks/add', null, array(
'task[name]' => $_POST['name'],
'task[body]' => $_POST['message'],
), array(
 'http://test.bathcomms.com/skin/frontend/bathcomms/default/images/logo.png   ));
}

Comment: Try with absolute file path, not relative one.

Comment: @llija ok I will try that way too but can you check this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997075/active-collab-notify-user-when-create-close-or-reopen-task-using-api

Comment: I provided the correct answer 10 days ago. That IS THE ANSWER ;-)

Comment: @llija I have asked new question please check below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997075/active-collab-notify-user-when-create-close-or-reopen-task-using-api

Comment: I hope you will have definitely solution for this new question.